# How to read two folder with Newman

Tags: postman, newman

I have the following line with Newman (works correctly), but I am looking to execute two folders at the same petition. First will be executed Login_full and then another (It is not essential)

```
newman run Example.postman_collection.json --folder "Login_full"  "" -e Environment1.json
```

How could I read two folders?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newman v4.1.0 comes with the ability to run multiple folders, like so:

```
newman run Example.postman_collection.json --folder "Login_full" --folder "another" -e Environment1.json
```

For a complete list of changes, check the Newman changelog: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.yaml