# how to run single request from the collection in newman

Tags: api, collections, postman, newman, runner

i have a collection in postman contain a lot of requests is there any option in Newman to run specific requests from this collection rather than create new folder for the specific request and run

Comment: Here is an affiliated issue on the `newman`'s GitHub repo: https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/276

Answer (score 23):

Yes, you can run a specific request in a collection runner in newman CLI with option `--folder`.

Documentation:

> CLI option : --folder "name"
>
> Run requests within a particular folder/folders or specific requests in a collection. Multiple folders or requests can be specified by using --folder multiple times, like so: --folder f1 --folder f2 --folder r1 --folder r2.

Example:

```
newman run "postman-collection-API" --environment "postman-environment-API" --folder request-name
```

Comment: Multiple `--folder` support appears to be a new addition to v4 BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519415/how-to-read-two-folder-with-newman

Comment: Doesn't work when you request in inside a subfolder `--folder <myFolder>/<myReq>`

Answer (score 3):

You can also run specific requests in the newman library as follows:

Documentation:

> `options.folder` - The name or ID of the folder/folders (ItemGroup) in the collection which would be run instead of the entire collection.

Example:

```
newman.run(
  { 
    collection: 'postman-collection-API',
    environment: 'postman-environment-API',
    folder: ['request-name', 'other-request-name']
  },
  function (error, summary) {
    console.log(`${summary.run.executions.length} requests were run`);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to run a single request from a collection using newman.
Refer [newman command line options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman)